# Solving a system of conjugated ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of ODEs that are conjugated (Not sure what it's called in english). We were asked to solve for the location of a particle on each axis as a function of time (z(t), x(t)).

I have the following two equations:

The ODE for the y axis is:

$$m \dot v_y=qv_0B_0$$ where q, v and b are all constants.

The ODE for the z axis is:

$$m \dot v_z=qE_0$$ where q and $E_0$ are constants as well. The y and z subscripts denote the axis in which the particle is moving.

I know that solving each one individually won't give me the answer I need. A hint or the nudge in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: I don't see the problem with solving them separately, if $q,v_0,B_0$ and $E_0$ are all constants. You get that $v_y,v_z$ are both linear in time and so $y,z$ are both quadratic in time.

Comment: @Ian I believe the word I was looking for is conjugate.

Comment: The usual word is "coupled". The problem is that your ODEs aren't actually coupled: $y$ and $z$ evolve independently of each other.